# Derivative inside a Series

Tags: series-expansion, summation

I have a function defined by a sum, which I would like to differentiate.

For example:

```
D[Sum[Subscript[c, n] r^Subscript[l, n] + 
  Subscript[d, n] r^-Subscript[l, n] + 
  Subscript[C, n] r^(Subscript[l, n] + 2) + 
  Subscript[D, n ] r^(2 - Subscript[l, n]), {n, 1, ∞}], r]
```

*Mathematica* seems to be able to do it, but it strangely takes a long time. Do you have any ideas why? Is it perhaps trying to sum the whole series first, and then tries to differentiate it, once it gives up summing?

Comment: This is a trivial problem, since you use capital letters `C` and `D` which are symbols of the system. Moreover you should play with with functions like e.g. `c[n]` instead of subscripts like `Subscript[c, n]`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Timing[D[Sum[
    Subscript[c, n] r^Subscript[l, n] + 
     Subscript[d, n] r^-Subscript[l, n] + 
     Subscript[u, n] r^(Subscript[l, n] + 2) + 
     Subscript[D, n] r^(2 - Subscript[l, n]), {n, 1, \[Infinity]}], 
   r]] // First

(*  0.  *)
```

It is, thus, so fast that Mma cannot see the time. The thing is that the variable C is reserved in Mma, and should not be used in the code. I replaced it by u.

Have fun!